# asset_path does not work in some views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can't resolve issue in rails 4 app. Help me please.

In controller in 'show' action I try to render view 'textile':

```
render "textile" if @wallcovering.material.id == 2 || @catalog.id == 10
```

In the view 'textile.html.erb' I have:

```
<%= image_tag "#{@catalog.title}/#{@wallcovering.title}.jpg", id: "textile_image" %>
```

but in page source in production there is a plain path, without md5, and image couldn't be found. Even

```
<%= asset_path("#{@catalog.title}/#{@wallcovering.title}.jpg") %>
```

shows me plain path. But I have another tag in this view:

```
<%= link_to catalog_wallcovering_path(@catalog, wallcovering), data: { remote: true, bgpath: asset_path("#{@catalog.slug}/#{wallcovering.title}.jpg") }%>
```

and asset_path works fine here.

There are some other controllers and views in my app, where are assets work fine.

I precompiled my assets by

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and then upload public assets to production server.

Where I am wrong?

Upd:

Changed `#{@catalog.title}` = "Caesar" to `#{@catalog.slug}` = "caesar" and it works now. What the mystery?

Comment: What is the parent directory of `#{@catalog.title}`? Gotta make sure it's in the precompile array as well as in the valid asset paths.

Comment: There is in array. I have another tag in this view: <%= link_to catalog_wallcovering_path(@catalog, wallcovering), data: { remote: true, bgpath: asset_path("#{@catalog.slug}/#{wallcovering.title}.jpg") }%> and asset_path works fine here.

Answer (score 0):

So, `asset_path` will return the same string you have passed in if the file doesn't exist. In your case `asset_path("#{@catalog.slug}/#{wallcovering.title}.jpg")` was working and `asset_path("#{@catalog.title}/#{@wallcovering.title}.jpg")` wasn't because they are different paths. When you access to a remote file, the path is case sensitive. I'm not sure, perhaps if you run the server on Mac this would work because Mac is case insensitive.
Hope this helps to clarify the issue.